# Inner join with linq using postgresql integer [] array

Tags: c#, postgresql, linq, npgsql

Is it possible to write this query with linq?

```
select y."ID", y."Name" 
from "Rezervasyon" as r 
inner join "Yolcu" as y on y."ID" = any(r."YolcuID")
```

Model

```
public class Rezervasyon
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public Yolcu Yolcu {get;set;}      
    [Column(TypeName = "integer[]")]
    public int[] YolcuID {get;set;}
}

public class Yolcu{
    public int ID{get;set;};
    public string Name{get;set;}
}
```

[db result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lO277.png)

```
public IQueryable<Rezervasyon> Get(){
    return Table.Where(x => x.YolcuID.Contains(x.Yolcu.ID));
}
```

Yolcu class is null.

edit :

[db schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dmh2N.png)

Comment: It is indeed possible. Try it out.

Comment: just remember that any inner join can be rewritten as a cross join with the on condition moved to the where clause

Comment: @juharr I've tried. but the Yolcu is empty. I added the code in post.

Comment: What is `Table`?

Comment: @NetMage I added the schema img.

Comment: 1. Don't put images in place of text/code. 2. Still doesn't answer the question "What is `Table`"?

Comment: sorry @NetMage  Table  : `DbSet<Rezervasyon> BaseRepository<Rezervasyon>.Table`

Comment: The problem is that your LINQ query above still does a regular join via Rezervasyon.Yolcu, which is a regular relationship - so the condition is for both the regular foreign key, and for the array contains.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Get all Rezervasyon with *all* Yolcu rows whose ID is in the Rezervasyon's int[]? Any reason you're not just using a regular one-to-many mapping approach?

Comment: My goal is not to use a second table. @ShayRojansky.

Comment: But you already seem to have two tables - one for Rezervasyon and one for Yolcu... If a single Rezervasyon acn have multiple Yolcu, and a Yolcu is only a string (and will never be more), then you can simply place an array of strings on Rezervasyon. Otherwise you need a classical one-to-many relational setup with two tables.